# c# label will not update when reading from file

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I am trying to update my label text with values from a file in a WinForms application. This is a simple 2-3 line file that contains FTP links based on the product selected from a combobox.

If I use a message box I can see that I am in fact getting the values I am looking for but they are just not updating on the screen.

I took a look at the BackgroundWorker process and most of the people that have to use this solution are complaining that the application is locking up while processing the action. My program is not doing this and is 100% functional during the product selection.

I have also tried things like ftpLabel.Refresh()/.Update() after setting the labels in my try and catch but it still does not update.

I even tried the "Do not use ever!" Application.DoEvents() and cannot get it to work. I am sure there is a much more simpler solution to my problem then going through the backgroundworker process. I am new to c# and did not understand how to set it up and am really hoping to find something that works.

My code is as follows:

```
    private async void productComboBox_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get selected product
        string selectedProduct = productComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        // Create the flow layout panel that will contain the links
        // Display the group box and set the name
        ftpGroupBox.Visible = true;
        ftpGroupBox.Text = selectedProduct + " FTP Links";


        // Create the flp
        FlowLayoutPanel ftpFLP = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        ftpFLP.Name = "ftpLinks";
        ftpFLP.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Label ftpLabel = new Label();
        ftpLabel.AutoSize = true;

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(selectedProduct + ".txt"))
            {
                String line = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                ftpLabel.Text = line;
                ftpLabel.Update();
               MessageBox.Show(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ftpLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            ftpLabel.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            ftpLabel.Update();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        ftpFLP.Controls.Add(ftpLabel);
        ftpGroupBox.Controls.Add(ftpFLP);

      }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the `productComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()` return the expected value? I'd guess it should be `productComboBox.SelectedText.ToString()`.

Comment: You do know how to use `async` modifiers?

Comment: @jAC You should set `label.Parent` property to `Control` on which label must appear or `ParentControl.Controls.Add(label)`.

Comment: @Onur oddly it does return the expected value but I will change it since you are correct and it would make more sense :)

Comment: @Reniuz only to the point of it telling me i needed it for the filestream

Comment: @Ruslan Veselov i should mention that I have a group box that is going to hold the dynamic FlowLayoutPanel control. So that would be the parent which is why i am adding the ftpLable to the FlowLayoutPanel first then adding it to the group box, should i not be doing that or is that what may be causing the problem? It does display as I would expect it to other than updating when I change the product

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the whole form? and the async modifier seems suspicious ^^

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and inspect some variables like filename?

Comment: @SebastianL If pull out Async than i cannot do the String line = await bit. Is there another way around that (sorry noob here). Also how would i refresh the whole form *blush*

Comment: @Onur yes i have and my results are fine. The message boxes i have in there are just for troubleshooting but they do display the proper contents of each file

Comment: To clarify you can see all controls but labels are empty right?

Comment: So the problem is not really related to reading files but only to update content. I'd simplify the problem by first testing to simply update a label with static content and adapt the solution found there to your "real" code.

Comment: first i would try `String line = await sr.ReadToEnd();` and not using async. if thats working just move the whole StreamReader stuff into another `Thread` if you want to do it async. And update your label in another event

Comment: @Reniuz i can see labels and content. So when i pick the first product i get the contents of that file in the label as expected, when i pick a different product the label is not updated to contain the new data from the file, however the message box i have is displaying the correct content. I just cant get it to update that to the label

Comment: @SebastianL I did change that after your suggestion but i get the same results. My intent was not to do multithreading but it was the example i found :). So now that i've change that i still get the same results

Comment: ok i'll try it now myself and post my results later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I get it what is wrong here :)

When you run code first time it is everything ok and it works as expected - you adding `FlowLayoutPanel`, `Label` etc. But second time you creating **new FlowLayoutPanel again** and after you adding it...somehow gets in place where you can't see it and you see the first FlowLayoutPanel in form.

So what you need to do is remove previously created `FlowLayoutPanel` with `Label` or reuse it.

EDIT:

To add dynamically `FlowLayoutPanel` and reuse it you can do it so (just painting idea, not actual code):

```
//Create local variable of panel
FlowLayoutPanel yourPanel;

private async void eventHandler()
{
  //this will create new panel if it is not existing currently
  if(yourPanel == null)
  {
     yourPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
     //add new control
  }

  Label yourLabel = new Label();

  //here you use newly created or reuse previously created panel
  yourPanel.Controls.Add(yourLabel);
}
```

And if you want to reuse label - just use the same idea with label.

Comment: thats what i found 5 sec ago ^^ but you were faster ^^

Comment: Oh! That makes total sense, so the second++ flow panel is there its just underneath the first one. So I have to ask, how would I reuse the same dynamic flow panel or remove it?

Comment: What do you need to add dynamically FlowLayoutPanel or labels?

Comment: @Reniuz really the only thing i need to add dynamically is the label. So maybe a simpler solution is to have the flow panel be static as its really not going to change. I am only using it for organization reasons.

Comment: @Reniuz actually the label doesn't even need to be dynamic, just the content :$

Comment: Yeah problem solved when i bring it to a much simpler state. Thank you all so much!